# Vestacp - exim mail forward goes to spam in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, forwarding, exim

I dont undestand why mail what forward mail re-send like spam. On server I use exim and VESTA Control panel. Here is source of the mail:

```
Delivered-To: emailforforward@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.158.78 with SMTP id h75csp14306ioe;
        Tue, 1 Sep 2015 14:59:53 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.112.64.228 with SMTP id r4mr14312689lbs.103.1441144793654;
        Tue, 01 Sep 2015 14:59:53 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <sendermail@gmail.com>
Received: from alfa.hostname.com (123-123-123-123.datacenter.com. [123.123.123.123])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z1si17722025lbw.159.2015.09.01.14.59.51
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 01 Sep 2015 14:59:53 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning sendermail@gmail.com does not designate 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.123.123.123;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning sendermail@gmail.com does not designate 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=sendermail@gmail.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from mail-la0-f42.google.com ([209.85.215.42])
    by alfa.hostname.com with esmtps (UNKNOWN:AES128-GCM-SHA256:128)
    (Exim 4.72)
    (envelope-from <sendermail@gmail.com>)
    id 1ZWtam-0005pP-Au
    for info@domain.com; Wed, 02 Sep 2015 00:59:48 +0300
Received: by laeb10 with SMTP id b10so9441190lae.1
        for <info@domain.com>; Tue, 01 Sep 2015 14:59:50 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
        bh=znPMRO2Q6GFf5sy8VwAXEJsHQaB1x8k+ht3bzxNhUI4=;
        b=gZ4Vo8NogOFY14nbTJmdYxAdFmNHmyAPtlzv5GVQXu2TNPEAXF/jl9bZlvJwwveBKF
         xgop3NxDH1Yj32Uz7RhQMP7DL7Ky/2B5ujvmjZRtPb1zkq/4/k9c2xyp/D5PlaAlKCY4
         6Nv5bBrppy6dTb1Aabl8tplY9T/atIJ9aNP05Tt7I7JbWKzrR5LBsz/nFVcDV8a5MH0L
         9FHJjQd90m4fsXBR2WbflvcQZllkqJojvgGPS4CN19DQzZgRP9bUIvfgElqvB34ZNvUj
         JDrTcSfh8Xz1XdiTkesftrc/5Rbq/z0xoC51w2aTGyqG1CIyCU2rcG/HVHZrttz+boJu
         uFTA==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.152.184.41 with SMTP id er9mr11827213lac.20.1441144790447;
 Tue, 01 Sep 2015 14:59:50 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.25.30.10 with HTTP; Tue, 1 Sep 2015 14:59:50 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Wed, 2 Sep 2015 00:59:50 +0300
Message-ID: <CAL+hCrnSTcvn5+Xr9Q2dHZzq9o4CL6D=GYdcuu39GOS0=i+uKw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: Name Sender <sendermail@gmail.com>
To: "domain.com" <info@domain.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11345e364dfdaa051eb6ab05
X-redirected: yes

--001a11345e364dfdaa051eb6ab05
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test

--001a11345e364dfdaa051eb6ab05
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">test</div>

--001a11345e364dfdaa051eb6ab05--
```

THank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want forwarding to work, you need to modify the mail. The `From` field needs to contain an address the forwarding server is authorized to send from. The `Reply-to` field may contain any address. In your case, that would be the original sender’s address.

However, I have no idea how you’d set this up.

Answer (score 0):

Your SPF record is incorrect

> Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning sendermail@gmail.com does not designate 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.123.123.123;
>   Authentication

Then, you should also add reverse DNS (rDNS) for your server's IP address and make it same as SMTP hostname.

Comment: Take attention that if forward, forward what is works from another server on cpanel:


Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning XXX@gmail.com does not designate 93.90.51.48 as permitted sender) client-ip=93.90.51.48;

About SPF: 
WHen i sent dirrectly mail from mail client, it goes good, domain have SPF:
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of *@domain.com designates 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.123.123.123;

Problem ONLY on forwarding

Comment: Well, it’s not his SPF record, it’s Google’s.